# PHP or Jquery for interpreting and formatting json data for polymaps?

Tags: php, javascript, json, maps, instagram

I'm pulling data from the Instagram API and caching it using php for use with a Polymaps application. My question is simple (but probably not simple) -- I've been approaching this from the standpoint that I should format my data in php and then make a json file I can use directly with polymaps.

Would it be better to just cache the json file and use javascript to pull the information I need from it?

Or is this mostly a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always favor client-side processing in these cases. Server-side processing tends to add up to server load. And it really depends on:

- whether JS is a must for your application (in this case, it is; because without javascript those maps are dead anyway and so it will be the processing )
- whether the processing mechanism is not hard to replicate and is not a company secret (this is up to you)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. It's a fairly standard polymaps setup, so it's nothing that needs to be kept a secret.